# Cannot get the contents of req in next.js API route

Tags: next.js

I am using 13.4.5 of next.js.
I am using API Route. Here is the code for (1). I am trying to get data by hitting the code in (1) using swr. But when I hit "http://localhost:3001/api/company/123/users?user_id=12" in the url
but I can't get the groupId. Please let me know if anyone can help me understand.
①

```
// app/api/company/[groupId]/users/route.ts
// route.ts
import { NextRequest, NextResponse } from "next/server";
import { parse } from "url";
import { apiClient } from "@/libs/axios";

export async function GET(req: NextRequest) {
  const { query } = parse(req.url, true);
  const { userId,groupId } = query as any;

  return NextResponse.json({ query });

  // const response = await apiClient.get<Graphs>(
  //   `/company/${groupId}/users?user_id=${userId}`,
  //   {
  //     params: { user_id: userId },
  //   }
  // );
  // return NextResponse.json(response.data);
}
```

②

```
import useSWR from "swr";
import { Items } from "@/generated/models";
import { apiClient } from "@/libs/axios-client";

export const useFetchItems = (groupId: string, userId: string) => {
  return useSWR<Items>(
    `api/company/${groupId}/users?user_id=${userId}`,
    async (url: string, userId: string) => {
      const response = await apiClient.get<Items>(url, {
        params: { user_id: userId },
      });
      return response.data;
    }
  );
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code:

```
export async function GET(req: NextRequest) {

  const content = await req.json();
  const { userId,groupId } = content as any;

  return new Response(JSON.stringify(content));
}
```